# Best natural language(s) for conveying, conceptualizing, teaching, understanding, and learning Probabilistic & Statistical concepts & theory?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, statistics, probability, language-use, concept-maps

English can be precise but it is rather 'flowery' and easily gets in its' own way.  East-Asian natural languages like Mandarin, Cantonese, Korean, and Japanese are notorious for permitting the simplification of mental arithmetic.  It has been argued this has something to do with numbers such as: 36 transliterating to "three tens and six."  In Indian English, 16/4 seems to be spoken as "Sixteen on Four" or "Sixteen by Four."  In American English we might say "Sixteen divided by..." or "Sixteen over..." (the latter example being somewhat less common).  Small mental or linguistic tricks can make a huge difference in the formation of an intuitive conception of various maths relationships, operations, and concepts. Again,

Q1: "[What are arguably the...] best natural language(s) for conveying, conceptualizing, teaching, understanding, and learning Probabilistic & Statistical concepts & theory??"

There are many indirect ways to attempt to answer the main question I present in this post; which of course requires subjective responses.  One might ask:

Q2: Which countries produce or employ the most Statisticians per capita?

Q3: Which is the ratio/percentage between the top native languages spoken by graduates of universities who study Probability, Statistics or an equivalent field heavy in these subjects?
Or employees of corporations who hold titles in positions that require a robust working knowledge of said fields?

Q4: How do these candidate languages, that differ in their approach from English, describe, verbally present, and or phrase to act as the building-blocks that lead to the development of a strong foundation in these fields?

Thanks!

Sincerely,
NaiveBaye aka Zorkv

Comment: The most important question to pose is if the language even makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit too blunt - but an essential insight in statistics is that correlation does not imply causation. Thus, the "sub-"questions (a) and (b) are actually not sub-questions since there is no reason to assume that answers to them will give an insights into the main question.

Comment: Could you check whether you meant to write “notorious”? That clause doesn’t seem to flow.

Comment: @Tommi, I decided to pose this very question because I am positing with this post that, for numerous reasons, English or whichever naturally-spoken human-language that said Maths is taught/explained using will ultimately and in some fashion, even if significate in comparison to the quality of instruction/instructor themselves (i.e., if the professor is highly gifted in their teaching abilities, I would imagine perhaps in their native tongue (but I could be totally wrong in this regard of course), this should have a profound and likely greater impact on the quality of the instruction/education.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck, thanks for the formatting tips.  I do see it reads rather silly in light of your comment.  However, seeing as this is an internet forum and not a Masters Thesis or Doctoral Dissertation...I'd like so see anyone actually genuinely attempting to assist with finding answers to my questions.

Comment: @NoYouNaiveBaye: Thanks for your response! Please note, though, that my comment was not intended as a formatting tip. I just pointed out that answers to Q2 and Q3 will not provide any meaningful insight into Q1. The fact that correlation does not imply causation is extremely important to interpret empirical data in a meaningful way - no matter whether you write a Doctoral Dissertation or ask a question on the internet.

Comment: It seems your question needs details or clarity and you added those as an answer.  My suggestion is to consider adding the details of your answer to your question and delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes much difference, especially after you get past the most basic counting and arithmetic.  That said, it does bring up natural questions as to the best languages to seduce someone in, to sell used cars in, or to recite poetry in.  E.g. English often look down on Germans, but Schiller is quite poetic.

Comment: In my example of counting in Japanese, I understand your argument.  However,  I am asking about building fresh, intuitive minds, for Probabilistic and Statistical intuition.  Are you familiar with the Triangle of Power (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sULa9Lc4pck?)? This is not a linguistic construct but a visual one to develop a more intuitive understand of the relationship between exponents, powers, and logarithms. This is a beautifully simple example of how a simple visual change permits a profoundly intuitive perspective of these easily misunderstood concept.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any research on language and probability in particular (but neither am I an expert), but you might want to get familiar with research on language and mathematics (mostly number sense and counting) to get a sense of the field.

For example, the book https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110661941 is not old and is free, and has several articles that touch upon language and mathematics learning or understanding.

> Fritz, A., Gürsoy, E. & Herzog, M. (2021). Diversity Dimensions in Mathematics and Language Learning: Perspectives on Culture, Education and Multilingualism. Berlin, Boston: De Gruyter. https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110661941